# How can I install linux sys/prctl.h to lion?

Tags: linux, macos, osx-lion

I am trying to install some program (stone, http://www.gcd.org/sengoku/stone/Welcome.en.html
) in Max OS linon (10.7.3) with Xcode (4.3.3).
However, when I make, the following error message appears.

> stone.c:231:10: fatal error: 'sys/prctl.h' file not found

I searched using "find" command, but this library does not to exist.
It seems that I need to install some linux library to develop in Mac OS, 
but I have no idea.

It would be very grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. The functionality described by `prctl.h` in Linux does not exist on Mac OS X.

Using XCode is just complicating things. `stone` is intended to be built from the command line, using `make`.

Comment: And if you build it with `make macosx`, it won't try to use `prctl()` (because OS X, like many other UN\*Xes, doesn't have `prctl()`; `prctl()` is a Linuxism), and it will build.

Comment: Correct. That's why I'm recommending that OP skip XCode. :)